# android recyclerview load more items on scroll using volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, scroll, pagination

I have a problem with Recyclerview load more items. First fetch data work perfectly. Added onScrolled method, added offset to request. try to display 10 records at a time (increase offset by 10 in each request and set limit on 10 by starting with offset 0 and increasing it each time when bottom is reached. Every request should return next 10 items). Please check my below code.

**PersonUtils.java**

```
public class PersonUtils {

    private String personFirstName;
    private String jobProfile;

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return personFirstName;
    }

    public void setPersonFirstName(String personFirstName) {
        this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    }

    public String getJobProfile() {
        return jobProfile;
    }

    public void setJobProfile(String jobProfile) {
        this.jobProfile = jobProfile;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    List<PersonUtils> personUtilsList;

    RequestQueue rq;

    String request_url = "https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/Vkg6e6Vcu";
    String url = "https://.../api/json/offset=";
static int total = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleViewContainer);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        personUtilsList = new ArrayList<>();


        sendRequest(request_url);
       // sendRequest(url, 0);


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                System.out.print("test");
                if(dx>0){

                }
                if(dy>0){
                    total = total+10;
                    System.out.print("testing");
                   // sendRequest(url, total);
                    sendRequest(request_url);
                }
            }
        });

    }


//    public void sendRequest(String request_url, int offsetIndex){
public void sendRequest(String request_url){
    // request_url = request_url+offsetIndex;
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    PersonUtils personUtils = new PersonUtils();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        personUtils.setPersonFirstName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        personUtils.setJobProfile(jsonObject.getString("id"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    personUtilsList.add(personUtils);

                }

                mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("Volley Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

}
```

**CustomRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<PersonUtils> personUtils;

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List personUtils) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personUtils = personUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(personUtils.get(position));
        PersonUtils pu = personUtils.get(position);
        holder.pName.setText(pu.getPersonFirstName());
        holder.pJobProfile.setText(pu.getJobProfile());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personUtils.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView pName;
        public TextView pJobProfile;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            pName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pNametxt);
            pJobProfile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pJobProfiletxt);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    PersonUtils cpu = (PersonUtils) view.getTag();

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), cpu.getPersonFirstName()+" "+" is "+ cpu.getJobProfile(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Required Output:
on loading call **sendRequest(String request_url, int offsetIndex)**

if user scroll then call **sendRequest(String request_url, int offsetIndex)**

Every request should return next 10 items

Comment: The pagination logic is not right here. You should only call next page one the recycler view has reached its end.

Comment: But my requirement is display 10 records at a time, onscroll load next 10 records. if user scroll then call service and add 10 to offset.